# How to install perl module without testing via `Module::Build`?

Tags: perl, module

I know I can skip testing while installing by via `PERL_CPANM_OPT` env variable and/or option to `cpanm --notest`

https://metacpan.org/dist/App-cpanminus/view/bin/cpanm#-n,-notest

But how do same while installing via `Module::Build`?

Next does not work:

`PERL_CPANM_OPT=--notest ./Build installdeps`

Comment: [installdeps](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Build#installdeps) allows you to specify which cpan client including its command line ist used. I.e. try `./Build installdeps --cpan_client 'cpanm -notest'`

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: this works, but you forget second `-` before `notest`: `'cpanm --notest'`

Comment: Also `force install` on CPAN-prompt will install regardless of test result. Testing will be done, however.

Answer (score 2):

may be thats way can helps you.

```
cpan -T <module>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install like this

```
cpanm -n Any::Distribution
```

and this provide you an install without tests